# Raspberry Pi outputs video only on second HDMI port of Dell U2414H monitor

Tags: hdmi, display, pi-zero-w

I have Dell U2414H monitor which has two HDMI ports. The problem is RPi works only when connected to second HDMI port, while I had no luck trying to make it work on first port.

When I connect RPi to first port, I get blank screen and monitor goes into sleep mode/power saving mode.

I think it's not the problem with monitor, because when I connect my laptop to either of the ports it works flawlessly. Also RPi works fine when connected to two different TVs.

It's strange to me, because it's:

- not RPi problem, because RPi works on 2 different TVs and one of the HDMI ports of monitor
- not monitor problem, because when I connect laptop then both HDMI ports work
- not cable problem

How can I diagnose this issue and possibly fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Your monitor seems to output incorrect EDID on the first HDMI input. I suggest you configure your RPi to use the right EDID:

1. Connect your RPi to the working port and run `tvservice -d edid.dat`
2. Place `edid.dat` on the boot partition and set `hdmi_edid_file=1` in `config.txt`

Alternatively, you can ignore EDID altogether using `hdmi_ignore_edid` or `hdmi_safe` settings.

If you want to get to the root cause of your issue, read EDID while connected to each port of your monitor, run these files through `edidparser` and compare.

Comment: Unfortunately, only difference between EDIDs on both ports is physical address. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9f63ef4bc47ae086ef63a269c41a1d73

Comment: @stil Then it's a mystery for me too.